# regex in order to write only tags (html,php)

Tags: php, html, regex, iframe

I have an HTML document which is pretty long. It has a table that may vary between 1000 and 1200 pixels wide (it changes each day). Lots of text, tables and sometimes embedded PDFs.

I want to display on another page a short preview (like on online newspaper, where you can find title, a few sentences, maybe an image and then a link to the complete article).

First problem: the page where I want the preview is only 800 pixel wide.

My first idea was (in order to display only 10 sentences):

```
$lineswritten=0;
$stream=fopen($document,"r");
while ((($line = fgets($stream)) !== false)&&($lineswritten<10))
{

   if($lineswritten>=10)
   {
         echo "$line";

         $line=trim($line);
         if($line!="")          // if line is blank don't count it as text
         {
           $lineswritten=$lineswritten+1;
         }
   }
 }
 fclose($stream);
```

But I have some problems. 
**First of all**: tags. Both the main and the preview pages are built with tables. If in the first 10 rows of the preview, they open a table but they doesn't close it, all the layout of the preview page is messed up.

I tought of checking for table tags (     and   ) with regex but I have not yet studied these expressions. 
Is it possible to check for these tags and write only them after row 10?

**Second problem**.
Images. I may have an image which is really big. Is it possible to retrieve just the image path from a  tag? If that could be possible I can check the image dimensions and eventually scale it down.

**Third problem**
I have pdfs embedded with codes like:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?  url=http://www.mywebsite.ch/pdffolder/8121202.pdf&amp;embedded=true" style="width:990px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Obviously width and height are not so easy: they may vary too. Is it possible to recognize strings like this and write them on the preview page with height:200px and fixed width of 700px ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explain how the width of your table changes each day? Can't you just set a fixed width using CSS? Also, you should consider embedding your PDFs using something like Scribd instead of iframes.

Comment: The 'original' page may contain one table, two tables or more, depending on the daily purposes. Even the width of such tables is variable. We had some times where the tables had to be fixed at 500 pixel or some day that we get 1000 pixel because they must contain big pictures. We have a CSS but it manages the web site, the page I am talking about is pure content.

Comment: Are you saying that your "content" and your "web site" are separate? Are you perhaps using an iframe to embed content? Also, you should consider using `div`s instead of tables to format your content. It's generally considered to be better practice (see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html[link]) Maybe also set a maximum width on your images using CSS so that your overall page width remains consistent.

Comment: If tags are the only problem, why not just use `strip_tags()`? :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex for manipulating HTML, use php's [DOM tools](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead.

for instance, the second problem (getting image paths from images) can be solved by using the [DOMDocument::getElementByTageName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method like so:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($table);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
    //do whatever with the image sorce
}
```

The intent of this code is clearer, and you don't have to write a very long, complex and hard to manage regex to accomplish it.